# d3js straight line color covered by other lines

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am using d3.js to draw a dependency graph looks like the picture below
[image: basic graph]

Users can search through the graph and the corresponding line will be highlighted.
However, as the line is straight, the vertical part of the line is actually the latter link. Let me show it by two pictures. When what we find in the graph is not the last children node of the root node, the vertical part of the line is not colored red as it is colored gray again by the latter children nodes.

[image: highlighted node not the last child node]

If the highlighted node is the last child node of the root node, the result is correspondent to our expectation as shown below:

[image: highlighted node is the last child node]

So what can I do to put the colored red line on the top layer or prevent it from being colored gray again?

Comment: I would probably use selection.raise() on the line when coloring it - but without seeing your code or a portion of, it is difficult to know what is a viable solution in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you are updating the color through the `update` selection in your data join,

As Andrew has stated in the comments,  you can probably use [selection.raise()](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/v3.0.0/README.md#selection_raise) in order to bring those nodes up front.
SVG elements are rendered in the order you append them, so the n-th child will be behind the n+1-th child as the latter is rendered on top of the former.

You would have to be careful, however, to call raise only in the nodes you are coloring orange, as calling it in all the nodes that are being updated will have no effect (remember that a node that is changing from orange to gray is also considered to be updating)

Without looking at your code, I believe there's not much more I can help you with